# Django 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, django, forum

Goal/tl;dr I want to call my added method from views.py when you submit the forum and use the stuff from the textfield to make a new post object.

I am new to django, and I have looked through other stack posts, but most of these errors seem to be for cookies or users.  I have also looked at the python documentation as most people have suggested, but I haven't seen all the pieces together and I am not sure how to get the textfield from the forum.  Correct code and/or and explanation of what I am doing wrong and how to do it would be much appreciated.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

views.py

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from blog.models import Post
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def home(request):
    try:
        p = Post.objects.all()
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response('index.html',
        {'post':p})

def post(request, uID):
    try:
        p = Post.objects.get(pk=uID)
    except:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response('post.html',
        {'post':p})

def delete(request, uID):
    try:
        p = Post.objects.get(pk=uID).delete()
    except:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response('delete.html',
        {'post':p})

def new(request):
    context = {}
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('new.html', context)

def added(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        p = Post.objects.create(text=request.text)
        p.save()
        return render_to_response("index.html", context)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url


from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<uID>\d+)/$', 'blog.views.post', name='Post Id'),
    url(r'^(?P<uID>\d+)/delete/$', 'blog.views.delete', name='del'),
    url(r'^new/$', 'blog.views.new'),
    url(r'^created/$', 'blog.views.added'),
    # url(r'^myApp/', include('myApp.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

new.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2> Create a new Post </h2>
        <form method="post" action="/created/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            Body: <input type="textarea" name="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean `request.POST['text']`.

You should probably investigate the forms framework though.